# scanf regex - C

Tags: c, regex, scanf

I needed to read a string until the following sequence is written: \nx\n :

```
(.....)\n
x\n
```

\n is the new line character and (.....) can be any characters that may include other \n characters.

scanf allows regular expressions as far as I know, but i can't make it to read a string untill this pattern. Can you help me with the scanf format string?

---

I was trying something like:

```
char input[50000];
scanf(" %[^(\nx\n)]", input);
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: scanf does not support regexp in any standard C.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> `scanf` allows regular expressions as far as I know

Unfortunately, it does not allow regular expressions: the syntax is misleadingly close, but there is nothing even remotely similar to the regex in the implementation of `scanf`. All that's there is a support for [*character classes*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) of regex, so `%[<something>]` is treated implicitly as `[<something>]*`. That's why your call of `scanf` translates into read a string consisting of characters other than `'(', ')', 'x', and '\n'`.

To solve your problem at hand, you can set up a loop that read the input character by character. Every time you get a `'\n'`, check that

- You have at least three characters in the input that you've seen so far,
- That the character immediately before `'\n'` is an `'x'`, and
- That the character before the `'x'` is another `'\n'`

If all of the above is true, you have reached the end of your anticipated input sequence; otherwise, your loop should continue.

Answer (score 13):

`scanf` *does not* support regular expressions.  It has limited support for character classes but that's not at all the same thing.

**Never use `scanf`, `fscanf`, or `sscanf`**, because:

1. Numeric overflow triggers *undefined behavior*. The C runtime is allowed to *crash your program* just because someone typed too many digits.
2. Some format specifiers (notably `%s`) are unsafe in exactly the same way `gets` is unsafe, i.e. they will cheerfully write past the end of the provided buffer and crash your program.
3. They make it extremely difficult to handle malformed input robustly.

You don't need regular expressions for this case; read a line at a time with [`getline`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) and stop when the line read is just "x".  However, the standard (not ISO C, but POSIX) regular expression library routines are called [`regcomp` and `regexec`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/regcomp).

Comment: Note that most (all?) real implementations of scanf (including on GNU systems) do not crash your program or do anything nasty on integer overflow.  Discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.std.c/P-VPAMpZu9c) suggests that the standard could be re-worded to require sane behaviour and probably no implementation would have to change.  (specifically [Keith Thompson's post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.std.c/P-VPAMpZu9c/6kELb3kuBPMJ)).  However, with the standard worded as it is, scanf on bogus input is only safe on "good" C implementations, and isn't portable.

Comment: And even without UB, I agree with point 3: recovering from matching failures is often difficult.

Comment: Note: Problem #2 can be avoided by using a length modifier.

Comment: @CoolGuy I generally think, if you have to take extra, optional steps to *avoid* shooting yourself in the foot, it's a badly designed API.