# How to get fixed size buffer from mmap area in C?

Tags: c, io, mmap

I want to do next:
I have a huge file(over 4GB). I want to mmap it and then to take from this mmapped area buffers of 128 bytes. how can I do it? To mmap file I use this:

```
int fd = open(file_name, O_RDONLY);
void* addr = mmap(0, /*ULONG_MAX*/100000000, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
```

After these strings I want to get described above buffers but I don't know how and I didn't find it in the web.

additional info: file_name is text file. it contains strings

UPD: I'll try to explain: I want to mmap file and then take from mmapped area 128 bytes(actually chars) and put it to some buffer. Now i use next code:

```
char buffer[128];
struct str* addr = mmap(0, /*ULONG_MAX*/128, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
scanf((char*)addr, "%s", buffer);
printf("%s\n", buffer);
```

But it doesn't work. So I'm looking for the solution.

Comment: `after these strings I want to get described above buffers` *SYNTAX ERROR*. Please elaborate/explain ...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "take from this mmapped area buffers of 128 bytes".  Can you please show any code you have already written for *that*, since that is the part that doesn't work?

Comment: For the record, I don't see anything obviously wrong with the `mmap` call itself, except that some systems may object to 100000000 not being a multiple of `sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)`.

Comment: I don't get it... you need the first 128 bytes of that file?

Comment: @DavideBerra, yes. Then I need the second 128 bytes. And so on

Comment: Ok @VasiliiRuzov i've proposed my solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you successfully `mmap`, the file's contents (up to the `mmap`'d size) are available in the memory region pointed to by `addr`. So you can just do

```
memcpy(buffer, addr, 128);
```

Comment: Technically not the file's _entire_ contents, only the first 100000000 bytes of it.  (100000000 ≈ 2^{26} is decidedly smaller than "over 4GB").

Comment: @nneonneo Thanks. It works. Do you know any solution to read string from mmapped area?

Comment: Use `strncpy` or something.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, okay, this isn't really a problem with `mmap`, it's a problem with `scanf`.  That's easy.  [Don't use scanf.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664664/scanf-regex-c/15664816)  To copy fixed blocks of 128 bytes out of an `mmap` area into another buffer, you want [memcpy](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy).

```
...
unsigned char *addr = mmap(0, /*ULONG_MAX*/100000000, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
unsigned char buf[128];
...
memcpy(buf, addr + offset, 128);
```

and that's all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print every block of 128 chars do this

```
char buf[129];

// put a nul char to ensure the string will be terminated
buf[128] = '\0';

// other stuff you've done
....

// get the file mapped to addr memory pointer
void* addr = mmap(0, /*ULONG_MAX*/100000000, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

long i = 0

while (i < 100000000)
{
    // copy out the 128 bytes of the block
    memcpy(buf, (char *) &addr[i], 128);

    // print it out
    printf("BUF: %s\n", buf);

    // move to the next block
    i += 128;
}
```