# Segmentation fault after successfully executing 3 lines

Tags: c, gcc, libc

This program work,
It reads a big log file line by line , After reading 3 lines , it shows segmentation fault .

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char *line;
  FILE *my_stream;
  char *my_filename = "log";
  my_stream = fopen (my_filename, "r");
  while(fscanf (my_stream, "%s", &line)!= EOF)
  {
  printf ("==> %s\n", &line);
  }
  fclose (my_stream);   
  return 0;
 }
```

OUTPUT

```
==> 123    ==> 12345    ==> 1234568 Segmentation fault
```

Comment: have you tried a debugger?

Comment: @FredrikPihl   no, let me know , which to use and how ?

Comment: if you're on a linux system, I'd recommend `gdb`

Comment: @Kajal - [gdb](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)

Comment: You may want to learn to use `getline`

Comment: @Kajal  before to go for debug I think you should read [buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) You code is buggy its easy to find..Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to allocate space for `line` either on the stack or the heap. Also do not pass the address of line to `fscanf` and `printf`.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char line[256];
    FILE *my_stream;
    char *my_filename = "log";
    my_stream = fopen (my_filename, "r");
    while(fscanf (my_stream, "%255s", line)!= EOF)
    {
        printf ("==> %s\n", line);
    }
    fclose (my_stream);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You haven't allocated memory for `line`. Either declare it as:

```
char line[256];
```

Or do  an `malloc` for it.

Note: you don't need `&` neither in scanf nor in printf if you are dealing with a string (%s format specifier)

Comment: 1+. Also, `line` is already a pointer. Doing `&line` will get the "pointer to the pointer", what is wrong in the both cases it is being used.

Comment: @KingsIndian   how can i do it with char *line; , not changed by an array

Comment: Also don't forget to check the return value of fopen, the value of `my_stream` in this case, to make sure you can actually read the file.

Comment: @Kajal Then you have to allocate memory using `malloc` (or calloc). do : `line = malloc(256);` before using `line`. i.e. right before the while loop. Note `256` is just number I used which you can change as per your needs.

Comment: @KingsIndian    char *line;
  FILE *my_stream;
  char *my_filename = "pwd.lst";
  my_stream = fopen (my_filename, "r");
  line = malloc(256);
  while(fscanf (my_stream, "%s", &line)!= EOF)
  {
  
  printf ("==> %s\n", &line);
  }
  fclose (my_stream);
 changed but still the same error

Comment: @Kajal Remove the `&` from fscanf() and printf() as noted in the answer and also mentioned by Havenard.

Comment: @Havenard, &line will get the "pointer to the pointer", let me know how , & line will get address of that pointer , is it again a pointer ??

Comment: Yes, but its a pointer to the pointer, not the pointer to the data. `line` is type `char*`, `&line` is type `char**`.

Comment: @Kajal `line` is a pointer to char. If you take `&line` then you get a pointer to a pointer whereas fscanf() and printf expects a pointer when you specify `%s` format specifier. So you are passing wrong pointers to both functions which is why you get crash.

Answer (score 2):

You have not allocated any space at all for the line.  `fscanf` is thus writing your logfile's lines into memory at some random location and clobbering whatever happens to be there.  You get lucky three times and then it blows up.

For this task you should ideally be using [getline](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline).  If you don't have that, [fgets](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) will do, but you will need to allocate it some space.  Think `char linebuf[SOME LARGE NUMBER]`.

[Never use `*scanf`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664664/scanf-regex-c/15664816)

Answer (score 2):

In the line `char *line` you allocate space for one pointer to a char. In your `fscanf` statement you read whole lines of text into that address. You never allocate any space for the text that you read with fscanf, so you overwrite lots of memory that is used for other things.

Comment: can you explain in detail , then how can i fix