# C programming language (scanf)

Tags: c, whitespace, scanf

I have read strings with spaces in them using the following `scanf()` statement.

```
scanf("%[^\n]", &stringVariableName);
```

What is the meaning of the control string `[^\n]`?

Is is okay way to read strings with white space like this?

Comment: I recommend the use of fgets.

Comment: Don't forget to read the newline you're leaving in the stream. Also, you probably want to specify a maximum length to avoid buffer overflows.

Comment: Bluepixy is right.  scanf is a big security risk.

Comment: "For me, scanf is a pain." -- It's not just you.

Comment: @ncmathsadist No. scanf isn't a security risk at all. The risk is the programmer who uses it incorrectly, completely ignoring the manual with some over-inflated sense of ego... If anyone who read this page were to take the time to patiently read the manual, they'd know *the other two virtually unknown problems with this code* and how to avoid those problems.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour `scanf` *is* a security risk, because it is *possible* to use it unsafely.  Blaming the victims of poor API design is a great way to ensure nothing will ever change.

Comment: @Zack `fgets` is also possible to use unsafely. In fact, that describes C. C isn't a security risk. It's the people who write poor C code who are security risks. Whether or not the design for scanf is *poor* is debatable; That's a matter of preference. The significant fact is that there's a manual that tells you all of the things you can expect to be safe and portable. If *you* don't read manuals before using standard functions (at least for the first time), then *you* are the security risk. Similarly, if you don't follow the road rules, you are a risk on the road. Don't blame the road...

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour People took that attitude for the past, oh, thirty years, and so there's thirty years of evidence demonstrating that *it doesn't work*.  The APIs need to be designed so that the path of least resistance is secure, or else the *API* is wrong.  And yeah, I say C is a security risk.  It's *possible* to use safely but it's so hard that you oughta look with great suspicion on anyone who proposes to use it for new code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This mean "read anything until you find a '\n'"

This is OK, but would be better to do this "read anything until you find a '\n', or read more characters than my buffer support"

```
char stringVariableName[256] = {}
if (scanf("%255[^\n]", stringVariableName) == 1)
    ...
```

Edit: removed & from the argument, and check the result of scanf.

Comment: +1 for correctly using the size of the variable in the format specification.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It's unfortunate that the field width seems to be the only focus. There are two other problems with this code. I wonder if anyone else will spot them...

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour: Address of array; and testing return value from `scanf()`?  Yes, you have to go with what's there...

Comment: I suppose this is the right point to trot out my [three reasons why `*scanf` should never be used at all](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664664/scanf-regex-c/15664816#15664816).  But it's been my experience that listing *all* the problems with someone's code when they just want help with one of them is a great way to make them stop paying attention.  (If they actually asked for a code review, that's different.)

Comment: scanf is very useful and powerful, and it work like all others things in C, if you know what you are doing, than go for it. If you don´t understand exactly how the function works, than go read the documentation before using it.
@undefined-behaviour thanks for the notes, going to fix my answer.

Answer (score 4):

The format specifier `"%[^\n]"` instructs [`scanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) to read up to but not including the newline character. From the linked reference page:

```
    matches a non-empty sequence of character from set of characters. 

If the first character of the set is ^, then all characters not
in the set are matched. If the set begins with ] or ^] then the ]
character is also included into the set.
```

If the string is on a single line, [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) is an alternative but the newline must be removed as `fgets()` writes it to the output buffer. `fgets()` also forces the programmer to specify the maximum number of characters that can be read into the buffer, making it less likely for a buffer overrun to occur:

```
char buffer[1024];
if (fgets(buffer, 1024, stdin))
{
    /* Remove newline. */
    char* nl = strrchr(buffer, '\n');
    if (nl) *nl = '\0';
}
```

It is possible to specify the maximum number of characters to read via `scanf()`:

```
scanf("%1023[^\n]", buffer);
```

but it is impossible to forget to do it for `fgets()` as the compiler will complain. Though, of course, the programmer could specify the wrong size but at least they are forced to consider it.

Comment: `scanf` does regular expressions?  I so didn't know that.

Comment: @cHao, it is not really a regular expression.

Comment: The `%[...]` format superficially resembles part of regexp syntax, but it's not a regular expression.

Comment: `buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = '\0';`... Furthermore, [did you expect this](http://ideone.com/SGCBM3)?

Answer (score 2):

Technically, this can't be well defined.

> Matches a nonempty sequence of characters from a set of expected
>   characters (the scanset).
>
> If no l length modifier is present, the corresponding argument shall
>   be **a pointer to the initial element of a character array** large enough
>   to accept the sequence and a terminating null character, which will be
>   added automatically.

Supposing the declaration of `stringVariableName` looks like `char stringVariableName[x];`, then `&stringVariableName` is a `char (*)[x];`, not a `char *`. The type is wrong. The behaviour is undefined. It *might* work by coincidence, but anything that relies on coincidence doesn't *work* by my definition.

The only way to form a `char *` using `&stringVariableName` is if `stringVariableName` is a **char**! This implies that the *character array* is only large enough to accept a terminating null character. In the event where the user enters one or more characters before pressing enter, scanf would be writing beyond the end of the *character array* and invoking undefined behaviour. In the event where the user merely presses enter, the `%[...]` directive will fail and not even a `'\0'` will be written to your *character array*.

---

Now, with that all said and done, I'll assume you meant this: `scanf("%[^\n]", stringVariableName);` (*note the omitted ampersand*)

You really should be checking the return value!!

A `%[` directive causes scanf to retrieve a sequence of characters consisting of those specified between the `[` square brackets `]`. A `^` at the beginning of the set indicates that the desired set contains all characters except for those between the brackets. Hence, `%[^\n]` tells scanf to read as many non-`'\n'` characters as it can, and store them into the array pointed to by the corresponding `char *`.

The `'\n'` will be left unread. This could cause problems. An empty field will result in a match failure. In this situation, it's possible that *no data* will be copied into your array (not even a terminating `'\0'` character).  For this reason (and others), *you really need to check the return value*!

Which manual contains information about the return values of scanf? [The scanf manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/scanf.html).

Answer (score 1):

Other people have explained what `%[^\n]` means.

This is ***not*** an okay way to read strings. It is just as dangerous as the notoriously unsafe `gets`, and for the same reason: it has no idea how big the buffer at `stringVariableName` is.

The best way to read one full line from a file is [`getline`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline), but not all C libraries have it.  If you don't, you should use [`fgets`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets), which knows how big the buffer is, and be aware that you might not get a complete line (if the line is too long for the buffer).

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour I can imagine a compiler that rewrites `char buf[N]; ... gets(buf);` as `fgets(buf, N, stdin);` but as far as I know, no compiler in production use actually does that.  Is that what you are thinking of?  Otherwise, please explain.

Comment: How does `realloc` know how many bytes to copy from the old to the new object?

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour: `realloc()` has to be designed to know how much space to copy; the memory allocators are responsible for knowing how much space was allocated.  The situation for `gets()` is different; in general, it has no way of knowing the size of the array (argument to function is passed to `gets()`).

Answer (score 0):

Reading from the man pages for `scanf()`...

> [      Matches  a  non-empty  sequence  of  characters  from the
>   specified set of accepted characters; the next pointer must be a
>   pointer to char, and there must be enough room for all the characters
>   in the string, plus a terminating null byte.  The usual skip of
>   leading white space is suppressed.  The string is to be made up of
>   characters in (or not in) a particular set; the set is defined by the
>   characters  between the open bracket [ character and a close bracket ]
>   character.  The set excludes those characters if the first character
>   after the open bracket is a circumflex (^).  To include a close
>   bracket in the set, make it the first character after the open bracket
>   or the circumflex; any other position will end the set.  The hyphen
>   character - is also special; when placed between  two other
>   characters,  it  adds  all intervening characters to the set.  To
>   include a hyphen, make it the last character before the final close
>   bracket.  For instance, [^]0-9-] means the set "everything except
>   close bracket, zero through nine, and hyphen".  The string ends with
>   the appearance of a character not in the (or, with a
>   circumflex, in) set or when the field width runs out.

In a nutshell, the [^\n] means that read everything from the string that is not a `\n` and store that in the matching pointer in the argument list.