# I am thinking about for loop termination is it halts the loop or what's the actual story

Tags: c

```
Int i,num=10;

For(i=1;i<=num;i++);

{

Printf("%d",i);

}
```

Whats is the output and why is that output only single number?

Comment: If you know that the output is a single number, why do you ask what the output is? What did you expect as output?

Comment: since this is not the code you compiled and ran, why did you post it here?

Comment: Looks dudes...i want to know what really happened in for loop...why is it printing only one Number. Last one... Ya can also write and run it in any language

Comment: @khanfaizan Check the answer. Let me know if it is not clear still.

Comment: @khanfaizan I understand you were trying to ask about loops in the abstract, and your code is meant only as an example of the *sort* of problem you're having, but it is still very important to post *complete programs that exhibit **only** the problem you're trying to ask about*, and to ask a separate question about each problem, so we can be sure we are all talking about the same thing.  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .  And don't use pseudocode unless you're asking a pure algorithms question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put your code within the for block.  Remove the semicolon

```
For(i=1;i<=num;i++)

{
// code here
}
```

Comment: @Argonaut  ya are write..i write this code like this

Comment: @ergonaut If you're going to post sample code with errors corrected, please make sure you correct *all* of the errors.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than marking you down and commenting on the question, I would like to emphasise so that you understand what is going on.

```
int i,num=10;

for(i=1;i<=num;i++);
{
    printf("%d",i);
}
```

The purpose of ';' -> semi colon is to terminate a statement. So when you use it at the end of the for loop you code becomes as follows. Then it treats the printf as a separate statement and executes it irrespective of the for loop.

```
for(i=1;i<=num;i++)
    ;

{
    printf("%d",i);
}
```

Coming back to the for loop it runs 10 times and increments the value of i from 1 to 10, breaks when it is 11. The loop doesn't do anything since we have a semicolon immediately. Once the loop finishes, it comes down to the printf and displays the latest value of i which is 11. Also you do not place an '&' before i in a printf. An '&' before a variable in 'C' is used to refer to its address and u use it only in scanf when you enter a value and store it in the address of the variable.

I think you are a beginner and though many have voted down, the reason I explained it because it took more than a year to understand what happens when I place a ';' at the end of for loop.

Answer (score 0):

The number isn't a single number,actually all the number outputs were displayed all together without any spaces between them.You should use "\n" to display each output separately to the next line.Also remove that ampersand(&) from "printf" as it shows the memory address instead of the actual number.Also no semicolon should be used in the for loop statement. Here's a correction of your code-

```
int i,num=10;
for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
printf("%d\n",i);
}
```

Comment: I placed ; deliberately.. Opens ya eyes

Comment: Don't place semicolon(;) on the for loop as the semicolon "stops" the code from running.

Comment: Ohh man..i deliberately did it...dont ya get that

Answer (score 0):

There is at least one error on almost every line of your code.

I am going to assume that you quoted only the body of your `main()` and that you did, in fact, `#include <stdio.h>` at the top.

> ```
> Int i,num=10;
> ```

C is case sensitive: `Int` is not the same as `int`.  The compiler should have said something like

```
test.c:3:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'Int'; did you mean 'int'?
```

> ```
> For(i=1;i<=num;i++);
> ```

Similarly, `For` is not the same as `for`.  This will be interpreted as a *function call*, to a function named `For`, which you haven't bothered to declare.  Since you can't put semicolons inside a function-call expression, you should get a whole cascade of error messages:

```
test.c:4:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'For' is invalid in C99
test.c:4:10: error: expected ')'
test.c:4:6: note: to match this '('
test.c:4:21: error: extraneous ')' before ';'
```

Correcting `For` to `for` reveals another problem, which I think is the problem you were originally asking about.

```
test.c:4:22: warning: for loop has empty body
test.c:4:22: note: put the semicolon on a separate line to silence this warning
```

By putting a semicolon at the end of the loop header you made *that* be the body of the loop.  The brace block afterward is executed only once.  (C allows brace blocks to appear anywhere a regular statement could appear.  This is rarely useful anymore.)

> ```
> Printf("%d",&i);
> ```

And again, `Printf` is not the same as `printf`.

```
test.c:6:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'Printf' is invalid in C99
```

But that's not the only problem with this: you are trying to print the *value* of the variable `i` but you pass `printf` the *address* of `i`.

```
test.c:6:15: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'int *'
```

The correct call would be `printf("%d", i);` (also you might want an `\n` in that format string).  I suspect you have been confused by the asymmetry between `printf` and `scanf`.  In most cases you do *not* have to take the address of each argument to `printf`, whereas in most cases you *do* have to take the address of each argument to `scanf`, because `scanf` needs to *write* to those variables.  It's best to forget `scanf` exists, because [it should never be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664664/scanf-regex-c/15664816#15664816), but it is still important to understand this difference because it will come up *every time* a C function needs to emulate out-parameters.

All error messages from `clang` ("Apple LLVM version 7.0.0"; I have no idea which version of upstream LLVM that corresponds to) in `-std=c99 -W -Wall -pedantic` mode.  You should probably use that mode yourself.  (The same command line options are accepted by GCC.  I don't know what the equivalent is for MSVC.)

Comment: I knw that dude ..just assume i write only a pseudocode here..without main and all

Comment: If I assumed you are writing pseudocode then I couldn't help you at all, because how would I know that your pseudocode syntax is case-insensitive but otherwise *exactly* like C including all its quirks?