# Adding 2 doubles and print them

Tags: c

Iam new to C and I have a problem with adding and printing some doubles in 09.3f format. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   double d, m, c;


   scanf("%1f", &d);

   scanf("%1f", &m);

   c = d + m;
   printf("%09.3f\n", c);


}
```

And I have typed twice `scanf`yet I can only insert 1 number, why is that?
what i get from the printf is 00000.000

Example: d = 5,125 and m = 1.256, then i want C to be: 00006.381

Comment: use `%lf` (not `%1f`) with `double`s in `scanf`

Comment: Are you trying to use `,` and `.` as the decimal separator with `d = 5,125 and m = 1.256`.  I have never come across a system that allows both.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here, might be **Input Buffer Problems With Scanf**. So, you can add a `space` in the `scanf`. like,

```
 scanf("%lf", &d);

 scanf(" %lf", &m);
```

Also, use `%lf` in `scanf` instead of `%1f`.

Comment: Whitespace is discarded automatically, so the space won't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

Code is using a width limit of `1` in `scanf("%1f", &d);`.  That digit one limits the user input to 1 non-whitespace character and then attempts to save the result in a `float`.  Results are not defined.

Be sure to enable all warnings.  Many compilers will warn that `double d; scanf("%1f", &d);` do not match.

To save input to a `double` use an ell `l`.  [@Alter Mann](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39370316/adding-2-doubles-and-print-them/39371380#comment66068534_39370316)  Be sure to check results too.

```
//          ell, not one
//          v 
if (scanf("%lf", &d) != 1) puts("Number was not entered.");
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `scanf` ever; it is [broken-as-specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664664/scanf-regex-c/15664816#15664816).

Use `getline` to read an entire line (if you don't have `getline`, `fgets` will do), and then `strtod` to parse it into numbers.  (In this case it's possible to do the entire job with just `strtod`, but you may find it easier to write code that splits up the line with `strsep` first.  If you don't have `strsep`, `strtok` will do.)

Once you make those changes your program should work.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but i also want to try it with scanf, The problem is I typed 2 scanf but it reads only one double. Why is that?

Comment: Probably the peculiar and inconvenient way `scanf` treats the space character *between* the numbers and/or the carriage return *after* one or both of the numbers, but I don't actually bother remembering how `scanf` works in detail, because it's so broken that the only thing worth knowing about it is that it shouldn't be used.

Comment: Thanks for your time and tips! getline also worked, and I figured it out with the scanf