# Resolving munmap warning message

Tags: c, memory-management, mmap

I'm writing a program and have gotten a memory location that I have stored as a unsigned int and the length of the mapping as an unsigned int and I want to unmap this.

My following approach generates the warnings:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘munmap’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]

/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/sys/mman.h:77:12: note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘unsigned int’
```

and here is causing me the warning:

```
//startAddr and addrRange are stored as an unsigned int, 
void unmap(mapping_t *maps, const int *curSize){
  int i = 0;
  for (; i < *curSize; i++){
     munmap(maps[i].startAddr, maps[i].addrRange);   
  }
}
```

My program also crashes when I hit the munmap, but I am assuming that has to deal with the warning in some way

definition of struct mapping_t as requested:

```
typedef struct mapping{
  unsigned int startAddr;
  unsigned int endAddr;
  unsigned int addrRange;
} mapping_t;
```

Comment: Post the definition of `mapping_t`.  And I sure hope you're not really stuffing a pointer value into an `unsigned int`.

Comment: the compiler sure thinks he is

Answer (score 3):

> I'm writing a program and have gotten a memory location that **I have stored as a unsigned int**

Do not do that.  Use `void *`, `char *`, or even `[u]intptr_t`.  Do not stuff a pointer into an `unsigned int`.  That is wrong.  Pointers are not `int` values and may not be properly represented by an `int`, which is why you get a warning.  Pointers are allowed to be converted to an `int` per the C standard - which is why you get a warning instead of an actual error - but there's no guarantee that the conversion back to a pointer value results in the same address.

> and the length of the mapping **as an unsigned int** and I want to unmap this.

Do not do this either.  Use `size_t`:

```
typedef struct mapping{
  void *startAddr;
  size_t addrRange;
} mapping_t;
```

You don't need `endAddr` as you have the start address and the size.  If you need the end address, you need to convert `startAddr` to a `char *` to compute the end address.

Comment: if I change to type `void*`, how would I go about reading an `unsigned int` into my `startAddr`? I altered how I was reading in my value like so: `sscanf(line, "%x-%x %s", (unsigned int*)maps[*curSize].startAddr, ...)` but it is causing my program to crash now on the my attempt

Comment: "Reading an `unsigned int` into my `startAddr` (with `scanf`)" would _also_ be a design error, on several levels. Most importantly, the address of a mapping in process A is the address returned by `mmap` to process A, *not* whatever process B thinks it is. Second, if your code is performance-critical enough to bother with shared memory then it's also worth using a binary serialization for your IPC messages. And finally, [never use `scanf` for anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664664/scanf-regex-c/15664816#15664816).

Answer (score 2):

you cannot use unsigned int for pointers. Use void *.

```
    typedef struct mapping{
      void * startAddr;
      void * endAddr;
      unsigned int addrRange;
    }   
mapping_t;
```