# Difference between `"%[^\n]"` and `"%[^\n]\n"` and `"%[^\n]%*c"` in C how do they work?

Tags: c, input, scanf

I could not find the answer anywhere else.

`%[^\n]` - When I run this one, `scanf` is getting input and terminating after I press enter. ( Probably leaving `\n` in the input system)

`%[^\n]\n` -  this one is getting the input but `scanf` is NOT terminating immediately after I press enter like the one above. I hit more enter and it makes more newlines. When I give a character and then press enter it finally terminates. Example:

```
int main(void)
{
    char s[100];

    scanf("%[^\n]\n", s);

    printf("%s", s);

    return 0;
}
```

**The results:**

[image]

Last one:

`%[^\n]%*c` -  When I give some input and press enter. `scanf` immediately terminates.

How do those 3 work and how do they differ?

Comment: aa yes but I would like to know how those 3 actually work, I am wondering the logic behind them. Why they behave in such a way,

Comment: Possible duplicate: [scanf regex - C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15664664/643383)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All 3 format begin with `"%[^\n]"`.

`"%[^\n]"` is poor code<sup>2</sup> that lacks a width limit and is susceptible to buffer overrun.  Use a *width* limit like `"%99[^\n]"`  with `char s[100];`.

`"%[...]"` does *not* consume leading whitespace like many other specifiers.

This specifier directs reading input until a `'\n'`<sup>1</sup> is encountered.  The `'\n'` is put back into `stdin`.  All other characters are saved in the matching destination's array `s`.

If no characters were read (not counting the `'\n'`), the specifier fails and `scanf()` returns **without** changing `s` - rest of the format is not used.  No *null character* appended.

If characters were read, they are saved and a *null character* is appended to `s` and scanning continues with the next portion of the format.

---

`"\n"` acts just like `" "`,  `"\t"`, `"any_white_space_chracter"` and reads and tosses 0 or more whitespace characters.  It continues to do so until a non-white-space<sup>1</sup> is read.  That non-whitespace character is put back into `stdin`.

Given line buffered input, this means a *line* with  non-whitespace following input is needed to see the next non-whitespace and allow `scanf()` to move on.

With `scanf()`, a `"\n"` at the end of a format is *bad* and caused OP's problem.

---

`"%*c"` reads 1 character<sup>1</sup> and throws it away - even if it is not a `'\n'`.  This specifier does not contribute to the return count due to the `'*'`.

---

A better alternative is to use `fgets()`.

```
char s[100];
if (fgets(s, sizeof s, stdin)) {
   s[strcspn(s, "\n")] = '\0';  // To lop off potential trailing \n
```

A lesser alternative is

```
char s[100] = { 0 };
scanf("%99[^\n]", s);
// With a separate scanf ....
scanf("%*1[\n]");  // read the next character if it is a \n and toss it.
```

---

<sup>1</sup> ...  or end-of-file or rare input error.

<sup>2</sup> IMO, worse than [`gets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2410359).