# how can I use scanf() to read a file including space in C

Tags: c, scanf

I am not allowed to call any function other in a C library other than `scanf`, `printf`, and `feof`.
When I try to use the code below, it only reads a file up to space char. Is there a way to read a whole line without using `"%[^\n]"`?
My end goal is to read the entire file using `feof` file but first, I need to know how to read a line using `scanf`. Is it possible?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){

  char ar[50];

  scanf("%s", ar);
  printf("%s", ar);

}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use `"%[^\n]"`?

Comment: The only way to get `scanf` to read a whole line at a time is with `"%[^\n]"`. At the other extreme, you can read one character at time with `scanf("%c", &input_char)`. In that case, it's basically the same as calling `getchar`.

Comment: BTW, [don't use feof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941). The return value from `scanf` tells you when you've reached the end-of-file. `feof` doesn't provide any information that `scanf` doesn't already provide.

Comment: The correct way to read a file a line at a time in standard C is with `fgets`. Your instructor is wrong to forbid you to use `fgets`, and you may tell them I said so. Moreover, you may tell them I said [`scanf` should never be used at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664664/scanf-regex-c/15664816#15664816).

Comment: how can I make a loop to read one line at a time without fgets?

Comment: @user3386109 `"%[^\n]"` fails to read a whole line aside form not reading the `'\n'`, is reads/saves nothing when the line is only `"\n"`.  Lacking a width limit, it is bad like `gets()`, and worse.

Comment: @chux I didn't say it was a good idea, only that it's the only way to read a whole line with one call to `scanf`. The OP had already said that using `"%[^\n]"` was not an option, so I didn't bother with adding all the fine print, caveats, and dire warnings.

Comment: Detail: " only way to read a whole line with one call to scanf" --> STL has "... each line consisting of zero or more characters plus a terminating new-line character.".  `"%[^\n]"` does not read a whole line, just most of it as it fails to read the last character of the line.  `"%[^\n]%*c"` reads a whole line, except a line like `"\n"`.  `scanf()` lacks a single format that reads all lines.

Answer (score 1):

Read one character at a time.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  char ch;
  while (scanf("%c", &ch) == 1) {
    printf("%c", ch);
  }
}
```

P. S. Don't ever do this for production code and never admit your did this on a résumé.

Follow [@zwol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64019669/how-can-i-use-scanf-to-read-a-file-including-space-in-c/64020235#comment113207825_64019669) advice.

---

"My end goal is to read the entire file using feof file " --> [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/2410359).